# Permission errors in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. When trying to write a simple script that deletes the contents of a folder and then fills it with files copied from a different folder, I always get a `PermissionDenied` error.

Details:

```
+ remove-item <<<<  D:\path\* -recurse
    + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (save.gif:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Where is the problem? I am able to manipulate both folders through Explorer. 
The error occurs both when running from a script file and from shell (using Windows PowerShell ISE).
The ISE process runs under my account. 
I'm running Windows 7 Professional and am a local administrator.

**Edit:** 
After Richard's suggestion, I tried the verbose mode (which seemed to have no effect).

```
PS Z:\> $error[0] | fl * -force

PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : System.IO.IOException: Not Enough permission to perform operation.
TargetObject          : D:\path\file.txt
CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\path\file.txt:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
ErrorDetails          : Cannot remove item D:\path\file.txt: Not Enough permission to perform operation.
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

I don't see anything of much use there (but thanks for the tips anyway).

**Edit 2:**
Okay, here's the script source:

```
remove-item D:\path_A\* -recurse
copy-item D:\path_B\* D:\path_A\
```

That's it. The remove-item seems to throw at every file.

Comment: Do you actually have permissions to delete the files **save.gif** and **file.txt** as documented in the errors?

Comment: Yes, when the console didn't work, the first thing I did was trying to remove them manually. (I also said this in the opening post, but maybe I was a bit vague. Sorry about that.)

Comment: Can you provide the script itself ?

Comment: Is UAC enabled? If so try running your PowerShell session as 'Administrator'. It really looks like you don't have permission to delete the objects. Can you post the ACLs for the directory?

Comment: @Greg: Oh, that fixed most of the problems! Thank you. (I'm quite new here; what do I do now? Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? Or do I do it myself?)

Comment: Ran into an interesting issue using the `-Exclude` switch, causing the same access denied issue. To get around I rewrote it to pipe Get-Item | Where-Object. Bottomline, `-Exclude` is screwy man...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is UAC enabled? If so try running your PowerShell session as 'Administrator'. It really looks like you don't have permission to delete the objects.

We have very restrictive security policies where I work and users not familiar with UAC get burned all the time.

Answer (score 136):

Have you try :

```
remove-item D:\path_A\* -recurse -force
```

Comment: +1 because (misleadingly) even with appropriate access, PermissionDenied errors are thrown if *read only files* exist within the directory being deleted, unless Force is specified.

Comment: remove-item C:\path\some.js -recurse -force ; gives me Access to the path is denied, run as Admin

Answer (score 6):

In addition to reasons mentioned in the above posts, i've observed that "Access Denied" error is thrown when the file is being accessed by a separate process (In my case, i had to stop the server before Rename-Item could be run successfully).

Answer (score 1):

After this error (and assuming at that point in it the most recent error):

```
$error[0] | fl * -force
```

will expand the details of the error and exception. That should give you more information.

Another thing to do is to switch on verbose logging

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
```

to get more details about specifically what operation is being performed when the error occurs.

Finally PowerShell ISE includes a debugger which allows you to step through your script.