# How to make sure Jenkins has permission to delete files

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am running jenkins on windows under a domain user with administration rights. Part of my build script delete previous artefacts. Jenkins will successfully build once, after that it fails with

```
You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.
```

On the delete artefacts line which looks like this:

```
Remove-Item -Path $pathArtifacts -Recurse
```

Jenkins created these artifacts so why can't it delete them? The job config is very simple and just runs a build.bat after svn checkout. The files are local and just on the C drive

Comment: Sounds very similar to this question; maybe you can use `-force`?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798272/cannot-delete-a-file-even-when-logged-in-as-an-administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-force was the answer. Simple

Thanks Christopher