# How to "resolve fatal: Not a git repository"?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I was trying to remove one sub-module from the project

Tried  **rm -rf .git/modules/submodulePath**

After that I am having the issue

**fatal: Not a git repository**

Comment: list your folder structure if possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

These two files contains absolute submodule path:

```
{submodule}/.git
.git/modules/{submodule}/config
```

So, if you moved the repo, the absolute path in these two files are not valid, and cause the 'not a git repository' error. Just fix these files manually.

**Update:**

1. Delete the relevant section from the .gitmodules file. You can use below command:

   ```
   git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section "submodule.submodule_name"
   ```
2. Stage the .gitmodules changes

   ```
   git add .gitmodules
   ```
3. Delete the relevant section from .git/config. You can use below command:

   ```
   git submodule deinit -f "submodule_name"
   ```
4. Remove the gitlink (no trailing slash):

   ```
   git rm --cached path_to_submodule
   ```
5. Cleanup the .git/modules:

   ```
   rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule
   ```
6. Commit:

   ```
   git commit -m "Removed submodule <name>"
   ```
7. Delete the now untracked submodule files

   ```
   rm -rf path_to_submodule
   ```

Comment: I am not able to find any folder related to the sub-module i removed.

Comment: @coreDeviOS updated the normal way to do the removal of submodule in git. Go through it and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: In my case i need to do a `git reset` after editing the .git/config file

Comment: Both of those files contain only relative paths for me. git version `2.27.0`.

Comment: I actually only had to do the `submodule deinit` here, thanks for the info!

Comment: For some reason only a few of the submodules in my project contained absolute paths, the rest of them contained relative paths. I changed the absolute path entries to relative paths and everything worked.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this and didn't have a `.git/modules` directory in my main repository.  I have one submodule 'build', so just removed any references and reinitialized it:

```
rm -rf .git/modules
rm -rf build
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, short and sweet.

Comment: This was a saver for me!

Comment: The Windows equivalent for these should be `rd /s /q <dir>` for cmd or `rd -r <dir>` in powershell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/97896/11502722

Comment: Actually, `Remove-Item <dir> -Recurse -Force` may be better for powershell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798272/cannot-delete-a-file-even-when-logged-in-as-an-administrator

Answer (score 12):

I've just hit this problem.

In my case, this was due to checkout branches with different submodules.

- One branch has some submodules, but
- the other has 2 more submodules.

For some reason, they were impossible to initialize with:

`git submodule update --recursive --init`

I've needed to manually delete this files/diretories before update worked properly.

```
{submodule-path}/.git
.git/modules/{submodule}/config
```

Comment: Deleting the <submodule-path>/.git file fixed this issue for me

Comment: For me alone with `rm -rf submodule-path`. Thanks ~

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this error after I moved a git repository to a different folder. When I looked in:

```
{submodule}/.git
```

I saw a single line with an *absolute* path, e.g.:

```
gitdir: /Users/ajx/Documents/repo/.git/modules/{submodule}
```

I changed this to a *relative* path, e.g.:

```
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/{submodule}
```

I'm not sure why git would hardcode absolute paths...

Answer (score 2):

You simply can update the .git file

> nano {my submodule}/.git

with the right gitdir.

Because i think you change the path of your folder

Answer (score 1):

In my case, When I try to `git commit -m "***"`,this problrm occurs:
fatal: not a git repository: library-sp18/../.git/modules/library-sp18

My solution:
delete the `.git` file in library-sp18 and `git init`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the submodule section from the repository `.git/config`
2. Delete submodule directores:

```
rm -rf {submodule-path}
rm -rf .git/modules/*
```

These are all the areas that submodule information is kept

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue when changing from my develop branch to a feature branch that contains a new submodule.

After testing all the above solutions, I noticed that the cause was a git config option: `submodule.recurse = true`

It was trying to fetch the module at checkout but the submodule was not well initialized.