# git changed location of repository. how to revert or fix to where it was

Tags: git, github

I accidentally tried to use git add -A from the functions folder, which was new to this repository. Now I can't push from anywhere without getting this error.

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro-5:pk2-angular-v1.0.0 apple$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 42186, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40253/40253), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42186/42186), 147.16 MiB | 3.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 42186 (delta 13516), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (13516/13516), done.
To https://github.com/pgwest/subscriptionQAFinal.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

Peters-MacBook-Pro-5:pk2-angular-v1.0.0 apple$ git add -A
fatal: Not a git repository: functions/node_modules/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/zlib/../../../../../../.git/modules/packages/grpc-native-core/deps/grpc/modules/third_party/zlib
```

I've tried checking the git config file and it looks correct. Why is git looking for a repository in functions/node_modules/... and how do I fix that? I also tried hitting git init. It didn't help...

Comment: I'm confused by your description. You say that `git push` gives you an error, but it looks to me like `git push` was totally successful. And then you did a `git add -A` that didn't work. Which thing is it that's not working for you?

Comment: The git add won’t work

Comment: That path resolves to `functions/.git/modules/packages/grpc-native-core/deps/grpc/modules/third_party/zlib` -- does that illuminate anything? Like is it related to your submodules setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- remove the obsolete submodule information (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719020/6309))
- re-declare the submodule (using the right path for the repo) with `git submodule add`
- add again, commit and push.